# Group by. Ignore value in group clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a complex sql query, with several joins and subqueries. I want to know if there's a simple way to generate several groups using a GROUP BY clause for the same vale of the grouping fields, when this fields have some special value.

For example, if I'm grouping by fieldA, and fieldB, I get groups for diferent values of fieldA and fieldB, but when fieldA takes a special constant value like "specialValue", generate different groups for each record.

For example, if I have this records:

```
fieldA       | fieldB | fieldC 
_______________________
val1         | val2   | 1
val1         | val2   | 2
val2         | valx   | 3
val2         | valx   | 4
specialValue | vala   | 5
specialValue | vala   | 6
```

Selecting (fieldA, fieldB, max(fieldC)), Grouping by (filedA,fieldB) but ifgoring "specialValue" in fieldA, I would obtain the following results:

```
fieldA       | fieldB | fieldC 
_______________________
val1         | val2   | 2
val2         | valx   | 4
specialValue | vala   | 5   <-- Two rows
specialValue | vala   | 6   <--
```

I want to get it in the simpliest possible way, if it's possible without join or subqueries, because the query is already too complex.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, MAX(fieldC)
FROM table
WHERE fieldA <> 'specialValue'
GROUP BY fieldA, fieldB

UNION ALL 

SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC
FROM table
WHERE fieldA = 'specialValue'
```

?

Or alternatively with a `SUBSELECT`, although the availability of `ROW_NUMBER` and the `OVER` clause will depend on your version of SQL Server<sup>1</sup>.

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, MAX(fieldC)
FROM (
    SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, 
    case when fieldA = 'specialValue' then 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY fieldA) 
    end as rownum
    FROM t
) as subselect
GROUP BY rownum, fieldA, fieldB
```

---

<sup>1</sup> 2008 to present - [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: The first option is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using cube and/or rollup.

Answer (score 0):

Does the table have a primary key column that is different from these? You could do:

```
group by case when fieldA = 'specialValue' then primarykey else fieldA end
```

Comment: Almost, I can't select fieldA value or join by it because is not always contained in the group clause